# Cannot format nullable decimal using ToString("#.##")

Tags: linq, format, decimal

How do I format a nullable decimal such that it's string output is formatted to two decimal places?

```
Salary = g.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Salary))
.Select(x => (decimal?)decimal.Parse(x.Salary))
.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
.Sum().ToString();
```

The above works but sometimes yields a decimal results that is very long

```
203827.82763651324038269
```

I would like to format the result to two decimal places

```
203827.83
```

Since my desired output is a string I thought I could just use

```
.Sum().ToString("#.##);
```

Bu t I get an error `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments` which I think is due to the results being a `nullable decimal`. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, [`Nullable(T).ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't take any arguments. Instead, you can use good old fashioned `string.Format` or the string interpolation shorthand:

```
var result = g.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Salary))
    .Select(x => (decimal?)decimal.Parse(x.Salary))
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    .Sum();

Salary = $"{result:#.###}";
```

However, it's not clear why you are casting to `decimal?` here, why not simply this:

```
Salary = g.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Salary))
    .Select(x => decimal.Parse(x.Salary))
    .Sum()
    ToString("#.###");
```

Of course, I would suggest keeping the `x.Salary` values as `decimal` rather than `string`, but that's a different story.

Comment: I figured using `.DefaultIfEmpty(null)` was the best since the value could be null.

Comment: So there is no need for `.DefaultIfEmpty(null)` right?

Comment: Correct, or a cast to nullable decimal.

Comment: Probably a whole different question but when I remove `.DefaultIfEmpty(null)` and the `(decimal?)` I sometimes get a `sequence contains no elements` error. I have these in there in case there is junk in XML it comes from  (like letters for example)

Comment: Oh... well if you don't always have rows, then try `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)` instead of `null`. That way your sum value will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right.  The nullable decimal's ToString doesn't take any parameters and has no overloads.  You need to access the Value of the nullable decimal:

```
var Salary = g.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Salary))
.Select(x => (decimal?)decimal.Parse(x.Salary))
.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
.Sum();
var result=Salary.HasValue?Salary.Value.ToString("#:##"):"";
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. The LINQ statement is part of a `Select( new { ...}).ToList()`. Not sure how to pull this part out.